# How to change array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this in JavaScript:

```
[
  {"heure":"22:04:20","payload":"28-67"},
  {"heure":"22:07:27","payload":"28-43"},
  {"heure":"22:08:08","payload":"28-30"},
  {"heure":"19:00:00","payload":"32-23"}
]
```

and I would like to transform it like this to display it on a graph:

```
[
  {"heure":"22:04:20","data1":"28","data2":"67"},
  {"heure":"22:07:27","data1":"28","data2":"43"},
  {"heure":"22:08:08","data1":"28","data2":"30"},
  {"heure":"19:00:00","data1":"32","data2":"23"}
]
```

How can I do this easily?

Comment: Try writing some code and if you fail share your attempt. e.g. write a function that converts one of the items in your array into the desired structure and then map that function over your array.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I was going to write and answer, but it is kind of difficult, when it looks like you want someone to write it for free because you didn't try.  Try using JavaScript map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split the payload value into data1 and data2 properties. So `string.split` works for that.

You could use `Array.map` like this:

```js
var arr = [{"heure":"22:04:20","payload":"28-67"},{"heure":"22:07:27","payload":"28-43"},{"heure":"22:08:08","payload":"28-30"},{"heure":"19:00:00","payload":"32-23"}];

console.log(arr.map(function(item) {
  var data = item.payload.split('-');
  return {
    heure: item.heure,
    data1: data[0],
    data2: data[1],
  };
}));
```

Comment: Good and easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 3):

you can iterate over the array, for each object split payload string using .split('-') and new key values to the object, finally remove key payload from that object. something like this:

```js
var arr = [{"heure":"22:04:20","payload":"28-67"},{"heure":"22:07:27","payload":"28-43"},{"heure":"22:08:08","payload":"28-30"},{"heure":"19:00:00","payload":"32-23"}];

arr.forEach(function(x){
 var payload = x.payload.split('-');
 x.data1 = payload[0];
 x.data2 = payload[1];
 delete x.payload
})

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `map` function to iterate through the array and split the payload.

```
let r = [
    {"heure": "22:04:20", "payload": "28-67"},
    {"heure": "22:07:27", "payload": "28-43"},
    {"heure": "22:08:08", "payload": "28-30"},
    {"heure": "19:00:00", "payload": "32-23"}
];

r = r.map(x => {
    let myData = x.payload.split('-');
    return {heure: x.heure, data1: myData[0], data2: myData[1]}
});


console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method on the array. This is the exact purpose of mapping.

Here is a code snippet doing exactly what you are wanting.

```js
// Create the array.
var array = [
  {"heure":"22:04:20","payload":"28-67"},
  {"heure":"22:07:27","payload":"28-43"},
  {"heure":"22:08:08","payload":"28-30"},
  {"heure":"19:00:00","payload":"32-23"}
];

// Map the old array to a new array.
var newArray = array.map(
  (data) => {
    // Take each value in the array and map to the new data spec.
    // Split the data portion on the hyphen.
    var splitData = data.payload.split("-");
    return {"heure": data.heure ,"data1": splitData[0], "data2": splitData[1]};
  }
);

// Print out the new array. Just for testing purposes.
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
array.forEach(obj => {
 const [data1,data2] = obj.payload.split("-");
 Object.assign(obj, {data1,data2});
});
```

Comment: Could the people who vote here 1)decide, 2) explain downvotes ?

Comment: I did not down vote but I imagine it is because you have written an obscure solution that is hard for people to understand with no explanation.Try explaining why you use const and why you used Object.assign.

Comment: @bhspencer as the OP hasnt tried anything, i give him sth to work on... ;)

Comment: Also your solution does not remove the payload property from the items. So yeah, you get a down vote.

Comment: @bhspencer as i havent copied the original one, modifying it is a bad idea. And who cares about that extra prop? ( but i appreciate that youve explained your downvote ;))